# modify_if : apply predicate function to a dataframe

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to apply modify_if function to a dataframe with character values:

```
> dataframe
  col_1   col_2   col_3
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                 
 1 840    1097    989            
 2 s      s       s            
 3 781    9021    9006
```

I would like to insert thousands separator in character columns to get the following result:

```
> expected_dataframe
  col_1   col_2   col_3
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                 
 1 840    1 097    989            
 2 s      s        s            
 3 781    9 021    9 006
```

I don't know how to call the cells in the predicate function. I tried to use nchar function but I'm facing the following error:

```
> modify_if(dataframe, ~ nchar(.x) >3 , ~ stri_sub( ., nchar() - 3, nchar() - 2) <- " " )
Error: Predicate functions must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a logical vector of length 102
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`modify_if` allows selecting *which columns* to mutate, it doesn’t filter rows. In fact, you’re better off using table functions here (i.e. `mutate`), not ‘purrr’ verbs.

Instead, your mutation function itself must test whether each given value is longer than 3 characters. The logic of the formatting is also quite a bit more complex than simply adding a whitespace after three characters; so I’ll use the existing implementation provided by `format` rather than rolling my own:

```
add_thousands_sep = function (x) {
    num = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
    result = ifelse(is.na(num), x, format(num, big.mark = ' ', scientific = FALSE))
}

mutate(dataframe, across(everything(), add_thousands_sep))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 

Do you know how to justify the cells at the right side ? I think my trial  does not work because the vector is numeric and not character : `add_thousands_sep = function (x) {
  num = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
  result = ifelse(is.na(num), x, format(num, big.mark = ' ', justify = "right", scientific = FALSE))
}

result<-mutate(dataframe, across(everything(), add_thousands_sep))`

Comment: @Anna How are you outputting the table? Just on the R console or in a document? Normally things like right-justification (but also adding thousands separators etc.) is done *in the result document* via formatting options (e.g. in HTML or LaTeX), rather than in the R value.

Comment: you're right ! My output is in excel. I put the row data in a sheet and with formulas I put them in an other sheet with the good formating (colors, borders...). The data is centered in the first sheet but it does not impact the second sheet.

Comment: @Anna Ah, unfortunately I don’t know how to create Excel files with formatting in R, since I’ve never needed to do this. Plain CSV does *not* support formatting. The ‘r2excel’ can probably do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Base R:**

```
> as.data.frame(t(apply(dataframe, 1, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) if(!is.na(as.numeric(y))) format(as.numeric(y), big.mark=' ') else y))))
  col_1 col_2 col_3
1   840 1 097   989
2     s     s     s
3   781 9 021 9 006
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Very useful and powerful !

Comment: That’ll fail for e.g. `100000`; It also performs the `as.numeric` operation twice, redundantly.

Comment: Thank you. What should I do if my dataframe contains numbers bigger than 9999 ?